# In SQL server how do I order table rows by insertion order if primary key is GUID?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, guid

I've started using GUIDs over auto-increment integers for my primary keys.

However, during development I'm used to querying (from SQL management studio or visual studio) database in order to see what records my application just inserted, and I'm pissed off by the fact that I cannot order by primary key desc in order to see the most recent records.

Is there a way to accomplish tihs?

Comment: you never actually could know teh insertion order even with identies, as a longer insert process may mean that 5 was actaully inserted after 6. If you want to know the insertion order, then add a dateInserted column with a default value of getdate(). GUID are also a problem as a primary key for many reasons, please research this. You may want to consider using NEWSEQUENTIALID() to generate the GUIDs

Comment: @HLGEM - Using `SysUTCDateTime()` values can cut down on some of the confusion that occurs around changes to/from DST.

Comment: So, I assume that the short answer is NO :(

As I said, it only matters during development, so I'm OK to assume that largest id is the latest one. The same stands for timestamp. I'm well aware it's not necessarily unique, but for dev it would surely do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't order a GUID column based on insertion order. You'll need to rely on another column.

My suggestion is to add a column called `CreationMoment` as a `DateTime` with a default value of `GETDATE()`.  Theoretically you **could** have collisions (i.e. identical date / time of creation), so you'll have to decide if that data type is appropriate. In my experience it's never been an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, you have to add new field bigint with auto increment and rely on, no need to make it key. no collisions and no size problem with bigint

Answer (score 2):

Both @Yuck and @Sameh have good answers, but I think a TIMESTAMP column is a better fit for your needs.  It is guaranteed to be unique, and can be sorted using ORDER BY.

[MSDN - timestamp (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Be careful - a new timestamp value is assigned to a row on each insert and update.